# Get all SharedPreferences names and all their keys?

Tags: android, backup, sharedpreferences

I'm making backup program, that saved the phone `SharedPreferences` data into a file of my own structure. But I don't know how to list them all, which I need:

For example, 2 program saved their SharedPreferences with names `"Program A"` and `"Program B"`. I need to obtains thay String array contain these 2 names. Then, I use `getSharedPreferences` with "Program A", I need to get all keys that program has saved.

Is it really possible?

EDIT1: I DON'T know what programs/activities on the phone. I want to get ALL the `keys` that every programs saved. It just like you back up all your phone data, but only SharedPreferences values.

For example: Your phone has 10 programs, each creates a SharedPreferences named `Program 1` to `Program 10` (but of course, whatever name they want). And I would like to obtain all these `Program 1` to `Program 10` String. Then, if `Program 1` has 5 keys called `Key 1` to `Key 5`, I want to obtain these keys name.

EDIT2: According to `NikolaMKD` guide, this is what I've done so far, but the list return all programs, with "No Preferences" at all line, even at the first, I saved the SharedPreferences with my activity:

```
public class Test extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Test", 1);
        // No matter what name is: Test or the package name
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("TestKey", 0);
        editor.commit();

        List<ResolveInfo> Temp = 
            getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
                    .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER), 0);
        String[] App = new String[Temp.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < Temp.size(); i++) {
            App[i] = Temp.get(i).activityInfo.name;
            FileReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new FileReader("/data/data/"
                        + App[i] + "/shared_prefs/" + App[i] + "_preferences.xml");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                reader = null;
            }
            if (reader != null)
                App[i] += " (Have Prefereces)";
            else
                App[i] += " (No Prefereces)";
        }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, App));
    }



}
```

Comment: Your app sounds like it will need root privileges to run.

Comment: @Tom Dignan: I've already rooted it!

Comment: @Tom Dignan: Err, which you means? Root the phone, or root privileges for software? Could I solve this problem by anyway else?

Comment: Preferences are typically private to an application, so unless the device is rooted, you aren't going to be able to read the preference stores of arbitrary applications.

Comment: That doesn't suck.. That's called security....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Get all the _preferences.xml from

`/data/data/(package)/shared_prefs/(package)_preferences.xml`

Parse the XML, in the XML there is name for every key. I might misunderstood your question

Comment: Where's data folder? How do I read it? Do I need any permission? I can't even see this folder in `IO File Manager` or from my PC.

Comment: It's in your DDMS perspective of your IDE, then in File Explorer you can find phone directories. You can iterate it with the AssetManager. Permissions are based on your directories, -d--xwr--- something like this, but mostly all directories allow READING, since it is what you need.

Comment: What about package? I don't know which programs are on the device, I want to list them all? BTW, the data folder read from DDMS is a empty folder.

Comment: Maybe the program didnot saved any preferences. context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(Intent, 0); this is how you list all installed apps. Then use the list of the names, to iterate. The rest is logic..

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question. Please give me some advice. Thank you.

Comment: What's the output you get from   List<ResolveInfo> Temp = 
            getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
                    .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER), 0);
Log the items in this list see, what you get, compare it what you see in DDMS File Explorer. Also try iterating in all types of Intent Categories, like it is DEFAULT because there are many activities that use this and might save prefs.

Comment: Hey, do I need any privilege? My phone is rooted, but when I use `DDMS`, the whole `data` folder is still empty!

Comment: Try it on emulator, emulator has root access to system data. If you succeed on emulator, you'll also will on your rooted phone. I've never tried on actual device.. :)

Comment: The pleasure is mine. I'm glad I helped you.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
    Map<String, ?> allPrefs = prefs.getAll(); //your sharedPreference
    Set<String> set = allPrefs.keySet();
    for(String s : set){
        LOG.d(TAG, s + "<" + allPrefs.get(s).getClass().getSimpleName() +"> =  "
                + allPrefs.get(s).toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `sharedPreference.getAll();` which returns a `Map`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't think it is possible, You can't read other apps /data/data/ folder. On the emulator you can read them because you have root access.

Comment: Can I do that if my app has root  privilege?

Comment: Yes, it should. root has access to the /data/data folder & sub folders.    complete path to shared preferences file is /data/data/[package name]/shared_prefs/[file name].xml

Comment: <code>reader = new FileReader("/data/data/"
                        + App[i] + "/shared_prefs/" + App[i] + "_preferences.xml");</code> won't work because the xml file can be named something other than the package name. You would have to parse all the files under the /shared_prefs folder.

Comment: Thanks for your useful information! I've completed the program.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question, and I don't think there is a straightforward way of doing it. The best way to do it would be to either store these names in a DefaultSharedPreferences or some sort of global array, **or** you could retrieve the sharedPreferences from the activity itself if you know the preference resource id:

```
String packageName = String packageName = context.getPackageName(); 
Resources resources = context.getResources(); 
String sharedPrefName = resources.getResourceEntryName(R.id.PREFERENCES_RESOURCE_ID); 
sharedPrefName = packageName+"_"+sharedPrefName;
```

Comment: No, I mean all the program on the phone, which means, I DON'T know what programs/activities saved them. I've edited my post for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the xml files in your shared preference directory and get the name of all the files which are the shared preference names in your app.

```
File src = new File("/data/data/" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/shared_prefs");
if (src.isDirectory()) {
    String files[] = src.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (files[i].contains(".xml")) {
            reloadSharedPreference(context, files[i].replace(".xml", ""));
        }
    }
}
```