# Android Iterate through all the preferences

Tags: android, iteration, preferences, flat

Is there a way to iterate flat over all the preferences?
Right now I am asking for each preference

```
private void doSomething( Preference p ) {
    if( p instanceof PreferenceCategory || p instanceof PreferenceScreen ) {
        PreferenceGroup pGroup = (PreferenceGroup) p;
        int pCount = pGroup.getPreferenceCount();
        for(int i = 0; i < pCount; i++) {
            doSomething(pGroup.getPreference(i)); // recursive call
        }
    } else {
        ... process single preference ...
    }
}
```

I would like to do it this way:

```
int pCount = getTotalPreferenceCount();
for(int i = 0; i < pCount; i++) {
    // process getFlatPreference(i);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672949/get-all-sharedpreferences-names-and-all-their-keys

Comment: @baboo That link you gave is weird. It porposes to read and parse the XML where the preferences are inflated from. ::: Then you missunderstood my question, I want to write **less** code not **more**. ::: But anyway thank you for the link, it is definitely thinking outside the box!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure I see your problem with iterating though it this way, but if you want you could implement the following

```
private void callingMethod(){
    ArrayList<Preference> list = getPreferenceList(prefScreen, new ArrayList<Preference>());
    for (Preference p : list) {
        doSomething(p);
    }
}

private ArrayList<Preference> getPreferenceList(Preference p, ArrayList<Preference> list) {
    if( p instanceof PreferenceCategory || p instanceof PreferenceScreen) {
        PreferenceGroup pGroup = (PreferenceGroup) p;
        int pCount = pGroup.getPreferenceCount();
        for(int i = 0; i < pCount; i++) {
            getPreferenceList(pGroup.getPreference(i), list); // recursive call
        }
    } else {
        list.add(p);
    }
    return list;
}
```

this would allow you to make a flat preference list and then iterate through that list with a foreach loop.

Comment: I got no problem per se. I thought that maybe there are java system functions that iterate without having to write code like yours or mine.

Comment: no you searching the tree structure with Recursion, as far as I know there's no way that java supports this, you essentially want to flatten a tree data structure into a list and unless this has been done for you already (say on creation time of the list) you're going to have to make the flat list manually.

Comment: this should be a standard part of android documentation, searched the bloody cosmos for a way to get regular preferences instead of sharedpreferences

Answer (score 1):

You also can use this approach (code inside PreferenceFragmentCompat):

```
for (String key : getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().getAll().keySet()) {
    Preference p = findPreference(key);
    if (p != null) //do smth with pref
}
```

Some useless iterations, but it's not a problem for my project